# Linux User not able to login

Tags: linux, login, putty, login-manager

I am trying to create new users using `useradd` command using root credentials it is getting created properly but when I log in with the newly created user with its credentials using a PuTTY Console, I am able to enter the username but when I give the password, it hangs there for a long time until the PuTTY window session timeout happens and the window is closed. However when I use root credentials, it quickly enters the session.

I tried checking the `AllowUsers` under file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but I didn't find any matching entry, so, I manually tried adding `AllowUsers temipuser` where `temipuser` is the username I created. Post making this change from another PuTTY Console I again tried entering this username but it is again the same. I am totally clueless why is this happening.

Another thing is, if I add any user, say just `temipuser`, to the `AllowUsers` entry in the `sshd_config` file, will the root user still have access or will it not get access? I don't want to screw the things here. I understand `AllowUsers` lets only the specified users and denies others.

Comment: `/var/log/auth.log` should use some useful information.  Can you add anything you find to your question?

Comment: Agreed. Also adjust `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to set `LogLevel` to `Debug` while you try logging in to get as much information as possible.

Comment: Some Unix stuff chokes on usernames longer than 8 characters, your `temipuser` is 9... Can you log in locally (i.e., not over ssh)? BTW, I don't know offhand if `sshd` reads its configuration each time, you might have to restart it (or force it to reread configuration) after changes.

Comment: Are you able to ssh locally?  I.e. what happens if you log in as root and then run `ssh temipuser@localhost` and enter the user's password when prompted?

Comment: When i run ssh temipuser@<ip_of_server>, the same happens, it accepts username but hangs when i give password.

Comment: I cannot see any /var/log/auth.log file. Ok, after changing the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` `LogLevel` to `DEBUG`, i restarted sshd. I cannot see any auth.log file still.

Comment: What distribution (including version) are you using?  The log file may be named `/var/log/secure`.  Also, please try the SSH command I suggested verbatim, not using the public IP address of the server.

Comment: The RHEL distribution is: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga). I tried the ssh command and the same happens for it too, it take username and then hangs after i give password.

Comment: ok, I tried tail -f /var/log/secure and from another window i tried logging in to the ssh using the new username/pass and i can see the following messages:

`debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 778/516 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/tuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 778/516 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/tuser/.ssh/authorized_keys2
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for tuser from <ip_of_server> port 32352 ssh2`

Answer (score 4):

look for any relevant entries under `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log`. Also, make sure that you don't have custom rules added under `/etc/security/access.conf` which might access to the server for that user.

Those logs will contain information about failed logins and may indicate clearly what went wrong.

The `/etc/security/access.conf` file specifies (user/group, host), (user/group, network/netmask) or (user/group, tty) combinations for which a login will be either accepted or refused.

Answer (score 1):

Next to adding the user on the Linux machine, you'll have to generate a key (protocol type 2, preferably RSA) for that user as well. You can find instructions for that using Putty's key generator [here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey).

Select all of the text in the ‘Public key for pasting into authorized_keys file’ box in putty's key generator, paste it into a text editor and save it under the name `authorized_keys`.

In the home directory of the new user on the Linux machine, create a `.ssh` directory if it doesn't exist. This directory should be owned by the user, and only that user should have access to it (`chmod 700 .ssh`) Copy the `authorized_keys` file to this directory. You should change the permissions of that file with `chmod 0600`, and change ownership to the user.

Now the user should be able to log in.

Comment: You do not need a key in order to login via SSH. Password login is enabled by default and if the OP had disabled it, he/she would probably remember

Answer (score 1):

**Before trying these commands, either you need to become root user or you will have to run commands with sudo.**

After each change in file **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**, you need to restart ssh service. Command is:

```
systemctl restart  sshd.service
```

Any new user with which you want to do ssh login with password, you need to add that user to **AllowUsers** with space as separator for each user.

```
Eg:
AllowUsers root testUser
```

For root user to be active in login through ssh, you need to check **PermitRootLogin**, its value should be **yes** in file **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

***For Example:***
check the below sshd_config file. With this configuration you can also do ssh login using **testUser** and **root** user:

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
AllowUsers root testUser
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, your problem could be be related to a **permission issue**, since SSH asks you for a login (so it is not a port problem), and a password (so `PasswordAuthentication` is set to yes, which is the default anyway).

Indeed, the way `sshd` works by default is that it attempts reading public SSH keys *before* asking for a password, and if your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` has the wrong permissions, well, the manual says that `sshd` will not allow you to login (see below).

With no other information about your `sshd` configuration (is `AuthorizedKeysFile` still commented; do you actually use SSH keys; etc.), my guess was made by reading the `sshd` manual:

> ```
>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
>         Lists the public keys (DSA/ECDSA/RSA) that can be used for logging in as this user.
>         The format of this file is described above.  The content of the file is not highly
>         sensitive, but the recommended permissions are read/write for the user, and not
>         accessible by others.
>
>         If this file, the ~/.ssh directory, or the user's home directory are writable by
>         other users, then the file could be modified or replaced by unauthorized users.  In
>         this case, sshd will not allow it to be used unless the StrictModes option has been
>         set to “no”.
> ```

So. Can you `ls -l ~/.ssh/autorized_keys` and double-check that only the *user* can read that file?

**To make sure nobody but the user can read this directory, use this:** `chmod -v a-w,u+w ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Option `-v` is for `chmod` to inform you of the changes it made (if any), `a-w,u+w` is to remove the write permissions for all, and then give the user write permissions back.

Answer (score 0):

Did  you test `adduser temipuser` instead of `useradd temipuser`  ???

linux manual for sshd_conf said:

**AllowUsers**

```
    This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by 
spaces. If specified, login is allowed only for user names that match one of the 
patterns. Only user names are valid; a numerical user ID is not recognized. **By 
default, login is allowed for all users.** If the pattern takes the form USER@HOST 
then USER and HOST are separately checked, restricting logins to particular users 
from particular hosts. The allow/deny directives are processed in the following 
order: DenyUsers, AllowUsers, DenyGroups, and finally AllowGroups.
```

So you don't have to add AllowUsers and if you add this option I don't think it prevent from remote root login if you enabled **PermitRootLogin**

Answer (score 0):

Check the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. Check if the "PasswordAuthentication" line is set to "no". Change this to "yes" and save the file. You have to do this as sudo. Once file is saved restart using command "sudo service ssh restart"

Answer (score -1):

Remove any failures login counts , reset with below command:

```
pam_tally2 --reset -u username
```

use this command to null the entries

```
cp /dev/null /var/log/lastlog
```